# Conflicting libraries System.Security.Permissions and mscorlib when updating from Unity 2021.3.13f to 2021.3.14f

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, unity-game-engine, playfab

I recently updated Unity from 2021.3.13f to 2021.3.14f. After update this error came up:

```
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.services.core@1.6.0\Editor\Core\Configuration\ProjectConfigurationBuildInjectorWithPlayerProcessor.cs(43,50): error CS0433: The type 'FileIOPermission' exists in both 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' and 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

So far what I know and tried:

1. Unity has updated its Services core lib in 2021.3.14f version:

   - com.unity.services.core: 1.5.2 → 1.6.0
2. Im using Firebase and Playfab in my project

   - To my knowledge Firebase is using mscorlib.
   - I tried resolving libraries through external dependecy manager, but with no success
   - I tried updating Playfab and Firebase to it's lastest version, but that didn't help either.
3. I tried switching to .net Framework instead .net Standard. That also didn't do anything

I scoured the internet for answers but I didn't find anything related to Unity.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the `Library` folder and let Unity reconstruct it?

Comment: Yes, several times. And if I edit the script it will just automatically regenerate every edited script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I am not sure whether this is right approach deselecting Auto-reference and validate-reference from inspector in unity resolved issue for me.